# How to store data in multiple "field collection table" fields

Tags: 7, services

I'm having problem while storing data in multiple field collection table fields, Here I have tried following JSON format of drupal 7 services.

"field_grp_travel_time": {"und":[ {"value":"1.5"}, {"value":"2"}, "value":"1"} ] }, "field_grp_contact": {"und":[ "50","10","2" ] } }

by using this json node is created successfully but collection fields are empty. Is there any problem in json or missing something?

[image: Field collection table]

Here, Group1 is "field collection" and "Contact","Travel time" is sub fields.

( Note : I have set "Number of values" : "Unlimited" for "Group1" )

Comment: Problem solved , I have used following json structure :

"field_group1":{
 "und":[
  {"field_grp_contact":{
   "und":"1"
  },
  "field_grp_travel_time":{
   "und":[{
    "value":"50"
   }]}
  
  },

  {"field_grp_contact":{
   "und":"8"
  },
    "field_grp_travel_time":{
   "und":[{
    "value":"1"
   }]}
  },
 ]}

I got an idea from this link **https://www.drupal.org/node/1354202**